# how to generate dashboard.html file as separate file than index.html in extent report 4.1.0

Tags: c#, specflow, extentreports

I am using extent report 4.1 with specflow C#. it is working fine but I don't see dashboard.html generated a separate file. I only have index.html with a dashboard view. I would like to have dashboard .html as separate file so that I can share that as part of the email body generated by Jenkins after execution.

Currently:[image]

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Is the dashboard view included in the index.html file? Or the dashboard file should be there, but it is missing?

Comment: my aim is to share dashboard info in email body that triggers from jenkins .for  that I require dashboard.html separated from index. html
my second issue is : though I see dashboard option like above but when I click on dashboard , 404 comes "dashboard.htm" is not found

Comment: Can you add more information about the configuration for this report? Are you doing this in Azure DevOps? Can you share the relevant part of your build or release pipeline YAML code?

Comment: no , I am not working on azure. What I need is to generate the 2 files 1. index.html & 2. dashboard.html